# what character to use to be the last in string comparison in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, string, sorting

In my app I read contacts from address book, but for some of them, the name fields is empty. I want to put them at the end of my list by using a special string. What sort of special string should I use to make sure when the array is getting sorted ascending, person with missing name is placed at the end of the array?

for example my name array is

```
array = @[@"Andy", @"Brad", @"Zoro", @"[missing name]"];

[array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

I have tried using `<UNKNOWN NAME>` or `[UNKNOWN NAME]` or `<UNKONWN NAME>` but they all turned out to be in earlier position than Andy

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with. Since I want to avoid array sorting after query from the database. I setup a fake string to people that doesn't have name. This might not be the most elegant answer but it will make people with this name appear last if I query from core data using name in ascending order.

```
// Person+UnknownName.h
@interface Person (UnknownName)

+ (NSString)unknownName

@end

// Person+UnknownName.m
#import "Person+UnknownName.h"
@implementation Person (UnknownName)

+ (NSString)unknownName {
    unichar lastcharacter = 0xffffffff;
    NSString * UNKNOWN_NAME = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&lastcharacter length:1];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4):

### Conventional

Don't use a special string for missing names; don't do unnatural things just because you are missing data. Write your own message that uses `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:`, and put it in your own category on `NSString`.

```
// NSStringEmptyLast.h
@interface NSString (EmptyLast)

- (NSComparisonResult)localizedCaseInsensitiveCompareEmptyLast:(NSString *)aString

@end


// NSStringEmptyLast.m
#import NSStringEmptyLast.h
@implementation NSString (EmptyLast)

- (NSComparisonResult)localizedCaseInsensitiveCompareEmptyLast:(NSString *)aString {
    if ([self length] == 0 && [aString length] == 0) {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    } else if ([self length] == 0 && [aString length] != 0) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    } else if ([self length] != 0 && [aString length] == 0) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else {
        return [self localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:aString];
    }
}

@end
```

Then, use:

```
[array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompareEmptyLast:)];
```

Don't be afraid to add messages for existing classes.

### Blocks

Or, if you don't want to write a category, use

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr
```

where `cmptr` is a `NSComparator` block, which should have the equivalent of the message given above.

Comment: The reason I am using special string is that I want to avoid extra sorting after loading from core data. I thought if the sorting can be done via nsfetchrequest so I dont need to do another sorting after coredata fetch.

Comment: I guess I didn't mention the whole requirement so if there is no other alternative I should choose your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: But if you modify the data, then at some point you will have to undo the change.

Answer (score 0):

Try using curly brackets: `{…}`, pipe: `|`, or tilde: `~`.